# Python Pandas and Seaborn date format issue: strftime working different for different seaborn graphs

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

So basically I have dates in the dataframe as shown below:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

data = {'date': ['January 2020', 'February 2020', 'March 2020', 'April 2020', 'May 2020'],
     'revenue': [29000,31000,32000,25000,34000]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])

plt.figure(figsize=(14,5))
sns.set()
ax = sns.barplot(data=df, x="date", y="revenue", ci=None)
ax.set_xticklabels(df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m'))
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

[This works as intended. The dates show in the format %Y-%m in order where you see all the dates are different. If you remove the line where I changed format using 'strftime', then the format of the dates would be '2020:01-01T00:00:00:00000000'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZcXU.png)

[Now all this works fine in the above example, but when I do the same thing as I'm pulling from my SQL Query, all the months come out the same exact (2020-07), even though they are unique when I don't alter 'strftime'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AtGb.png)

I would have thought it had something to do with my SQL query, but another SQL query in the same notebook works without any issues, without even having to alter 'strftime'. All I did for that was pd.to_datetime() and it worked and automatically formatted itself on the graph to "2020-07, 2020-08, 2020-09" etc.

What's going on?

Comment: "I would have thought it had something to do with my SQL query, but another SQL query in the same notebook works without any issues," So did you actually examine what you got back from the sql query you are trying to graph? Another query that produces different results is irrelevant.

Comment: Yes, it brought back results to me in the following format [June 2020, July 2020, August 2020]. This is the same format as the query for which the graph worked correctly.